# bundleRelease fails with "Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies FAILED"

Tags: android, react-native, bundle

When trying to bundle a signed release of my React Native App for Android (on Mac)

`./gradlew bundleRelease`

fails with message

```
> Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

When executing `./gradlew bundleRelease --info` I get this error:

```
> Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies FAILED
Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies in @react-native-community_async-storage Starting
file or directory '/Users/ingohinterding/github/codegreen/android/app/libs', not found
Caching disabled for task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
file or directory '/Users/ingohinterding/github/codegreen/android/app/libs', not found
Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies in @react-native-community_async-storage Finished
:app:collectReleaseDependencies (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.396 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

I added that folder `android/app/libs` and when I run `./gradlew bundleRelease --info` again this is the new error:

```
> Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies FAILED
Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies in @react-native-community_async-storage Starting
Caching disabled for task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies in @react-native-community_async-storage Finished
:app:collectReleaseDependencies (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.339 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Note: When trying `./gradlew assembleRelease`it builds successful, but the APK gets rejected from the Google Play Store because it is not optimized.

Since I'm a beginner at RN I'm not sure what to look for and which information is needed here. React Native version is `0.59.9`(lots of stuff breaks if I update so I'll try to keep it this version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was successful doing the following:

1. Update Android Studio to the latest version
2. Update Gradle to the latest version
3. build with `./gradlew bundleRelease --build-cache`

Hope this helps others with the same issue.